# Android SDK page is not responding in windows

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I am a beginner in android.I just install Android Studio 2.3.2 stable version. SDK is at location **C:\Users\Priya Jain\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**. but when I go to SDK Manager nothing is responding. Now how can I install all tools need for the android studio?
**Is there need to install SDK in its default location**
**EDIT**
[Here is my system configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5LaD.png)
When I click on SDK tools, SDK Update sites it is not responding even on SDK platform anything is **not clickable**.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSlv5.png).
   **I set a default location for SDK but not working.**
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your system configuration?

Comment: Please view edit

Comment: priya,you need to change sdk path .so please edit sdk path and link your local drive path where your sdk reside.got my point?

Comment: your image contain default path of sdk but as per you said you kept sdk in local drive.

Comment: I install it again and set default

Comment: so click on edit button and change path.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install SDK in default location You only need to set path of SDk in Android Studio:-

Go to

1) File -> project Structure into Project Structure

2)Left -> SDK Location

3)SDK location select Android SDK location and here you set your SDK path.

Answer (score 0):

You may place Android SDK folder anywhere on your hard drive, but make sure it's not protected. Just try with the following:
1. Goto **Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager**
2. In the opened window find **Android SDK Location** and click on **Edit** 
3. Again In the opened window find **Android SDK Location** and click on the choose directory icon having 3 dots.
4. Now locate path of immediate sdk folder inside which the **SDK Manager.exe** file exist, and save it by clicking **Next** button.
Now u will be able to launch SDK manager.

Comment: @priya Make sure u have SDK Manager.exe in the sdk folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. I used to have the same issue in the beginning. You may install android SDK wherever you want to place it, even in a portable hard drive. you just need to change settings in the android studio to search SDK in the location where you installed it instead of looking in the default folder. for this follow these steps.
1. Open Android Studio
2. Go to File-->Settings-->Appearance and Behaviour-->
                        System Settings--> Android SDK
3. On the top, there would be Android SDK Location box. Click on edit.[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I11pd.png)
6. A box will open. at the bottom there a box Android SDK Location. click on ... box.[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po8Ss.png)
4. Change directory to where you saved SDK folder and click finish.
5. Click Apply and OK.
It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

@priya, see attached image. you can select drive where sdk resides after automatically affect and it will display available android version.
[image: Image for edit setting]